# Git not able to switch branches, except master

Tags: git, github

I'm new to git and was trying to work on a forked and cloned repo. In my PC I can see branches.

```
c:\>git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/dev
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/upstream/dev
  remotes/upstream/master
```

And,

```
C:\>git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/dev
  origin/master
  upstream/dev
  upstream/master
```

But when I do

```
c:\> git checkout master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

c:\> git checkout dev
error: pathspec 'dev' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Could anyone tell me why am I not able to switch to `dev` branch? I googled a bit, updated git (now 2.18.0.windows.1). Still this issue persists.

**EDIT**: It got resolved when I was randomly trying things in desktop app. I opened windows git desktop software. Clicked the option "Add local repositroy" and selected the folder where I had cloned the repo. Then I clicked the drop down branches and I could see `dev` there. When I selected it, it switched to that branch and command prompt issue was also resolved. Now I can switch to either `master` or `dev`. I don't know what happened internally when I did that, but it's working now.

Comment: Switch to *dev branch*? As in *the one and only*? The problem here, though the error message given by git could be made a bit clearer about this, is that you have 2 dev branches, `origin/dev` and `upstream/dev`. Since git didn't find 1 branch, it doesn't know which one you would like to check out. `master` has already been checked out locally at least once so that will work but `git checkout dev` doesn't find a local branch named `dev` so it goes hunting for branches on the remotes, and since it finds 2, it doesn't know which one you mean.

Answer (score 4):

From `man git-checkout` (`git help checkout`):

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking
>              branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a
>              matching name, treat as equivalent to
>
> ```
>  $ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```

So, often, `git checkout dev` would just have worked and done the right thing. What makes it not work in your case is that you have two remotes, `origin` and `upstream`, both containing a `dev` branch, so Git doesn't know which one to check out.

In this case, you'll have to use the longer form instead:

```
git checkout -b dev --track origin/dev
```

The `-b dev` creates a local branch called `dev` so you don't end up in "detached HEAD" state. The `--track origin/dev` sets it up as a tracking branch so you can push and pull it properly.

Actually, `--track` gives you a sane default for `-b`, so you can shorten this to:

```
git checkout --track origin/dev
```

Comment: To be frank, the error message given by git could be made a lot clearer about this.

Comment: I somehow weirdly resolved the issue (see edit). Just wanna ask something, isn't this how it's typically done? Forked and cloned, then set the original repo as the upstream? So wouldn't this have two `dev`? One is my own cloned repo and another one the original repo? Don't know if that made sense, I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: I don't know the GitHub desktop app, but my guess would be that it defaulted to the `origin` remote to check out the branch. That, or it looked at the repo URL and used the one that is owned by your user account (which would also resolve to `origin`).

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Absolutely, the error message is awful. It probably stems from the fact that the `X` in `git checkout X` may refer to a branch, but also to a file or directory ("pathspec" in git-speak). It only starts looking for a file if it can't find a branch. That's no excuse, just an observation.

Comment: Note that you can spell the checkout `git checkout --track origin/dev` as well: the default for `--track` is to use `-b` with a "local-ized" rewrite of the remote-tracking name.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a local branch named as `dev`. You need to fetch the branches in your origin to your local *(your machine)* .

You may need to try something like this:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout dev
```

Comment: I tried that and it's going to a detached head mode. Like below,

Comment: c:\> git checkout origin/dev
    Note: checking out 'origin/dev'.

    You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
    changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
    state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

    If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
    do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

      git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

    HEAD is now at 455946b Gui thumbnails (#14)